# table-cell content is different sizes

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have number of circles with footer text displayed in a table. On all browsers the circle images are the same size, except for IE11 and edge.

This is what I currently have (sorry for the large css dump - I really don't know what is causing the issue):

```css
.circle-container {
  display: table;
}

.circle {
  display: table-cell;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle>p {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}

.circle>div {
  position: relative;
}

.circle>div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #54314E solid 4px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle>div>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.circle:hover>div:before,
.circle:focus>div:before,
.circle:active>div:before,
.circle.active>div:before {
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <p><b>Corporate &amp; <br>Institutional <br>Banking</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <p><b>Global <br>Transactional <br>Solutions &amp; <br>Client Experience</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <p><b>Financial Markets</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <p><b>International</b></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have noticed though that the issue is non-apparent when I remove the text under the circles:

```css
.circle-container {
  display: table;
}

.circle {
  display: table-cell;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle>p {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}

.circle>div {
  position: relative;
}

.circle>div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #54314E solid 4px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle>div>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.circle:hover>div:before,
.circle:focus>div:before,
.circle:active>div:before,
.circle.active>div:before {
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to retain the current functionality and layout.

**Note:** I do **not** know how many circles w/ text there will be as this is generated, however `p.length == .circle.length`. This is why I opt'd to use `table-cell` in the first place as I thought it would mitigate manual setting of widths at "run time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table-layout:fixed` only works when applied to `display:table` not `table-cell`, then add `width:100%`

**Note:** The issue was happening with latest Firefox

```css
.circle-container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%
}

.circle {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle>p {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}

.circle>div {
  position: relative;
}

.circle>div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #54314E solid 4px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  transition-property: top, right, bottom, left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle>div>img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.circle:hover>div:before,
.circle:focus>div:before,
.circle:active>div:before,
.circle.active>div:before {
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <p><b>Corporate &amp; <br>Institutional <br>Banking</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <p><b>Global <br>Transactional <br>Solutions &amp; <br>Client Experience</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <p><b>Financial Markets</b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <p><b>International</b></p>
  </div>
</div>
```